# how to get the Node CPU% and MEMORY% value using java io.fabric8 kubernetes-client library

Tags: java, kubernetes, fabric8

kubectl top nodes
NAME                               CPU(cores)      CPU%      MEMORY(bytes)      MEMORY%
 
gsdjsgfhdsgfz-12345665-jisj000000    934m                  24%         10439Mi                  82%
gsdjsgfhdsgfz-12345665-jisj000001   717m                  18%          9132Mi                    72%
gsdjsgfhdsgfz-12345665-jisj000002   1099m                 28%           7614Mi                 60%

how to get the CPU% and MEMORY% value using java io.fabric8 kubernetes-client library.

```
try (KubernetesClient k8s = new DefaultKubernetesClient()) {

NodeMetricsList nodeMetricsList = k8s.top().nodes().metrics();
for (NodeMetrics nodeMetrics : nodeMetricsList.getItems()) {
      logger.info("{} {} {}", nodeMetrics.getMetadata().getName(),
        nodeMetrics.getUsage().get("cpu"),
        nodeMetrics.getUsage().get("memory"));
}
```

}

getting output is:-
node name
cpu:-1094942089n
memory:-7830672Ki

how will take the percentage values?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had to implement this same feature recently, unfortunately I didn't find a way to get the percentages just by using the `top()` API alone, I had to perform two calls, one to `nodes()` in order to retrieve total capacity and another one to `top()` to retrieve used capacity. Then it was just a matter of calculating percentage.

A snippet of the working code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    KubernetesClient kubernetesClient = new DefaultKubernetesClient();
    Map<String, Node> nodeMap = kubernetesClient.nodes().list().getItems()
        .stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(node -> node.getMetadata().getName(), Function.identity()));
    List<NodeUsage> usageList = kubernetesClient.top().nodes().metrics().getItems()
        .stream()
        .map(metric -> new NodeUsage(nodeMap.get(metric.getMetadata().getName()), metric.getUsage()))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
    System.out.println(usageList);
  }

  private static class NodeUsage {
    private final Node node;
    private final BigDecimal cpuPercentage;
    private final BigDecimal memoryPercentage;

    private NodeUsage(Node node, Map<String, Quantity> used) {
      this.node = node;
      cpuPercentage = calculateUsage(used.get("cpu"), node.getStatus().getAllocatable().get("cpu"));
      memoryPercentage = calculateUsage(used.get("memory"), node.getStatus().getAllocatable().get("memory"));
    }

    private static BigDecimal calculateUsage(Quantity used, Quantity total) {
      return Quantity.getAmountInBytes(used)
          .divide(Quantity.getAmountInBytes(total), 2, RoundingMode.FLOOR)
          .multiply(BigDecimal.valueOf(100));
    }

    public Node getNode() {
      return node;
    }

    public BigDecimal getCpuPercentage() {
      return cpuPercentage;
    }

    public BigDecimal getMemoryPercentage() {
      return memoryPercentage;
    }
  }
```

Comment: the cpu % is very correct
but the memory % i can see small variation

Comment: i have edited my answer with some small corrections, using .getCapacity() for this is not correct as not all capacity is usable, changed for .getAllocatable(). Also changed rounding mode from CEILING to FLOOR. Results should be the same now :)